# Python: Matrix extract does not display head

Tags: python

It seems to be simple, but I cannot get it run properly with attribute "head()", the code as follows give output

```
import numpy as np
matrix_X_train = np.load('matrix_X_train.npy')
total_area = matrix_X_train[:, 0]
print(total_area)
living_area = matrix_X_train[0:1]
print(living_area)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm7s0.jpg)

Here is it..

```
import numpy as np
matrix_X_train = np.load('matrix_X_train.npy')
total_area = matrix_X_train[:, 0]
print(total_area.head())
living_area = matrix_X_train[0:1]
print(living_area.head())
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibfU3.jpg)

The **head()** attribute generates error "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'head'", what is the workaround for it?

Comment: Why do you think numpy arrays have an attribute/method `head`?